# Inplace editing of DNS records via SSH with sed/awk or the likes

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have many files in a single directory with 3 lines I need to edit if the first line is edited, but I cannot wrap my head around how to do it.
The point is to change my MX records from pointing to my server, to pointing to mail. instead and have that point to the servers IP.  This makes migration in Cpanel a lot easier.  I have thousands of records to go through.

DNS updates

Line 1:

```
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  0   servername.com.
```

If the last block is "servername.com", it should be changed to mail.example.com instead like this

```
example.com.    14400   IN   MX 0  mail.example.com.
```

If nothing is changed here, I want to skip the next parts and just go to the next file in the directory.

Line 2:

```
mail IN CNAME servername.com
```

For any record where line 1 was changed, this line should be changed to

```
mail IN A 8.8.8.8
```

Line3:

Increment the serial number for the DNS record in any file where Line 1 was changed.  The 10 digits can be anything, but are always the first thing on that line, and always on line #5.

```
2015061800  ; serial, todays date+todays
```

-OR-

```
2015061800 ;Serial Number
```

I need to set the digits to today's date in format **YYYYMMDD09**

Here is what I have so far:

```
#! /bin/sh
while IF= read dname
do
sed -i -r "s/MX\s*0\s*servername.com/MX 0 mail.$dname/g" $dname.db
done < dirlist.txt
```

This takes dirlist.txt which contains a list of domain names, finds and replaces servername.com with mail.domainname.com for the file domainname.com.db.  This works BUT the original field can have different numerical values between MX and servername.com.  I would like to ignore the field, but writing

```
MX\s**\s*servername.com
```

instead does not seem to work.  So how do I ignore that 0 or 100 or whatever the value is?

Also, IF an edit is done above, I would like to loop the below statement for the same file.  If an edit is NOT done, I would like to break the loop and continue to the next file.

```
#! /bin/sh
while IF= read dname
do
sed -i -r "s/mail\s*IN*\sCNAME\s*servername.com/mail IN A 8.8.8.8/g" $dname.db
done < dirlist.txt
```

After that is done, again assuming the first edit was done, I would like to edit line 5, first block of the file to the value YYYYMMDD09.

```
#! /bin/sh
while IF= read dname
do
sed -i '5s/.*/\t\t2015121009 ; serial, todays date/' $dname.db
done < dirlist.txt
```

Seems to do the trick, so its really just the looping and the wildcard/ignoring the numerical value that doesnt work as intended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a Q&A site, not a free coding service.  Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck, and we are happy to help you understand how to solve your problem.

Comment: What tripleee said. But for some guidance, look to `man date` for your date format, and `man awk` for the rest. I wouldn't recommend sed for this one.

Comment: Ofc, I feel really stupid I didnt add it.  I have edited the post now to include what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is not very clear (actually confusing), but for the first line you can do this and perhaps get you started for a prototype for the rest.

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {sub("servername.com.$","mail."$1)}1' file
```

will change the final field "servername.com." with "mail." prefixed first field, only for the first line.  If you provide multiple input files, it will do the same for all files (but the output will be only one, which can be solved).  Note that this preserves input file spacing.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ignore the field, but writing
>
> ```
> MX\s**\s*servername.com
> ```
>
> instead does not seem to work.

There between the two `\s*` you have only a `*`, but to match any number of any character, you need `.*`, so `MX\s*.*\s*servername.com` works.

> If an edit is NOT done, I would like to break the loop and continue to
>   the next file.

You can combine all three edits into one `sed` call. Since you want the second and third substitution take place only if an edit is done on line 1, you'd wrap all in a commands block for line 1 `1{…}` and advance inside this block to the next lines if so (with `n`, see below).

> I would like to edit line 5, first block of the file to the value
>   YYYYMMDD09.
>
> ```
> …
> sed -i '5s/.*/\t\t2015121009 ; serial, todays date/' $dname.db
> ```

To automatically insert today's date, you could use

```
    s/.*/\t\t`date +%Y%m%d09` ; serial, todays date/
```

(but within double quotes).

Altogether:

```
while read dname
do
    sed -i "1{s/MX\s*.*\s*servername.com/MX 0 mail.$dname/;tcontinue;b
        :continue;n;s/mail\s*IN*\sCNAME\s*servername.com/mail IN A 8.8.8.8/
        n;n;n;s/.*/\t\t`date +%Y%m%d09` ; serial, todays date/}" $dname.db
done < dirlist.txt
```